# Why does R re-size everything in the plot but not the text when exported?

Tags: r, pdf, plot

Whenever I try to export R plot, either with RStudio with with `pdf()`, I find that all the elements are re-sized accordingly but not the text. This can lead to titles being cut off even.

Try resize this plot in Rstudio (or use `pdf("plot.pdf", width, height)` in base R):

```
ggplot(data=data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y=rnorm(100)), aes(x, y)) +
  geom_point() +
  geom_text(aes(label=rep("a", 100))) +
  labs(y="Title that is very loooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooooong")
```

When `width x height` is `5 x 5`, the text is oversized and the title is cut-off. But as `10 x 10`, everything fits in.

So it seems like the text remains at a constant "size" no matter what I specify for the size of the plot. Is this a correct understanding of how R export graphics?

If that's the case, what do you typically do to make sure that the text in the exported graphics fit in?

Comment: Yew=s your understanding is correct although I think its more design decision on the part of Adobe and not R's authors. It's not a feature of the pdf format that the fonts will scale.

Comment: Furthermore the behavior you see in a pdf viewer will probably vary depending on its design. This is more of an RStudio question since base R has no SaveAs function with sizing options.

Comment: I tested using `pdf('file.pdf', width, height)` and the result is the same. The problem seems to be with exporting `pdf`, not with `RStudio` per se.

Comment: That was sort of my point. If you tell the `pdf()` graphics device to make the output a particular size (via the RStudio choices)  and give it text, also of a particular size that happens to be larger than the output  ... what should you expect? I think you should expect the text to extend beyond the plot.

Comment: There's probably a grid-equivalent to the base-graphics `strwidth` function. Type" `help(pac=grid)` ... yep, there it is: `stringWidth`. It's help page refers you back to `strwidth` for conceptual matters. This has nothing to do with "data-visualization".

Comment: @BondedDust, this isn't an RStudio or PDF viewer issue. If I understand the question, the issue is that the relative scaling of plot features changes when you change the size of the PDF device. For example, try these: `pdf("small.pdf",5,5); plot(1,1); dev.off()` and `pdf("large.pdf",10,10); plot(1,1); dev.off()`. Now display the graphs in your favorite PDF viewer. If you zoom so that each is the same physical size on your screen, you can see that the relative size of the text is much smaller in "large.pdf" relative to "small.pdf".

Comment: Okay, I see the intuitiveness behind the behavior. With `pdf`, the size of all the elements are fixed, including text, line, tick mark, etc., and re-sizing the graph only changes the size of the graph while maintaining the relative position of the elements. So the best practice is probably: 1) when plotting specify elements' sizes that make sense relative to one another, then 2) when exporting, choose a plot size that everything fits in, 3) import into latex using `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]`

Comment: I've wondered about this myself. When you, for example, make the device larger, the plot elements get scaled down in size, so that they take up proportionately less space. I'm curious why the scaling works this way.

Comment: @eipi10 I think it's because the elements' size is fixed, no matter the size of the plot. In your example, `pdf("small.pdf",5,5); plot(1,1); dev.off() and pdf("large.pdf",10,10); plot(1,1); dev.off()`, if you display the two graphs, zoom so that the physical size on screen is `5x5` and `10x10`, the element sizes should be the same between the two plots.

Comment: I have a similar issue when I resize the plot in R-Studio and save it as a png. It seems the text stays the same size in pixels while much of the rest of the elements scale.

Comment: @eipi10: It was hard to tell exactly what the "issue" was. If you display a pdf image in a viewer and "stretch" the viewing window it's very possible that the displayed image may increase in size and that the apparent size of the characters will increase. The original questioner was not particularly specific about what he expected and why he thought it _should_ be expected.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I finally see the intuitiveness behind this behavior. When I posted the question, I expect R to resize all the elements inside the graph when I resize the graph.

However, in fact, the size of ALL elements are fixed, including text, line, tick mark, etc., and re-sizing the graph only changes the size of the graph while maintaining the relative position of the elements.

To see this, run `pdf("small.pdf",5,5); plot(1,1); dev.off() and pdf("large.pdf",10,10); plot(1,1); dev.off()`. Then, if you display the two graphs, zoom so that the physical size on screen is `5x5` and `10x10`, the element sizes should be the same between the two plots.

So the best practice is probably (please share your practice):

1. when plotting specify elements' sizes that make sense relative to one another,
2. when exporting, choose a plot size that everything fits in,
3. import into latex using `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth, height=\textheight,keepaspectratio]`