# How can I prevent resizing of fonts, plot objects etc. in R?

Tags: r, plot

I want to have multiple plots in the same image, and I want to have a different number of plots depending on image. To be precise, I first create a 1x2 matrix of plots, and then a 3x2 matrix of plots. I want to use the same basic settings for these two images - the same font sizes especially, since this is for a paper and the font size has to be at least 6 pt for a plot.

In order to achieve this, I wrote the following code for R:

```
filename = "test.png"
font.pt = 6    # font size in pts (1/72 inches)
total.w = 3    # total width in inches
plot.ar = 4/3  # aspect ratio for single plot
mat.col = 2    # number of columns
mat.row = 1    # number of rows
dpi = 300

plot.mar = c(3, 3, 1, 2) + 0.1
plot.mgp = c(2, 1, 0)
plot.w = total.w / mat.col - 0.2 * plot.mar[2] - 0.2 * plot.mar[4]
plot.h = plot.w / plot.ar
total.h = (plot.h + 0.2 * plot.mar[1] + 0.2 * plot.mar[3]) * mat.row

png(filename, width = total.w, height = total.h, res = dpi * 12 / font.pt, units = "in")

par(mfrow = c(mat.row, mat.col), mai = 0.2 * plot.mar, mgp = plot.mgp)

plot(1, 1, axes = T, typ = 'p', pch = 20, xlab = "Y Test", ylab = "X Test")

dev.off()
```

As you can see, I set a total width of 3 inches and then calculate the total height for my image, so that the aspect ratio of the plots is correct. The font size only changes the resolution by a factor.
Anyway, the problem is now that the font size changes significantly when I go from `mat.row = 1` to `mat.row = 3`. Other things change as well, for example the labelling of the axes and the margins, even though I specifically set those before in inches. Have a look:

When 3 rows are set (cropped image):

[image: 3 rows]

When only 1 row is set (cropped image):

[image: 1 row]

How can I prevent this? As far as I can see, I did everything I could. This took me quite a while, so I'd like to get this to work instead of switching to `gglplot` and learning everything from scratch again. It's also small enough that I really hope I'm just missing something very obvious.

Comment: maybe you want `par(ps = font.pt)`?

Comment: [This SO question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30467015/why-does-r-re-size-everything-in-the-plot-but-not-the-text-when-exported) might be helpful.

Comment: eipi10: Maybe I'm misunderstanding this, but all that the guy in that answer finds out is that elements stay the same size when you change width and height. I know that, it's specifically what I try to use here. My problem is that this is NOT how it works in my specific example.

Comment: Nathan Day: I've tried that before and it didn't help. Which is not surprising, since in my example it doesn't even work with the default font size. The font size in both cases is the same; the resolution is the same; and yet, one text is larger than the other. It currently seems like a bug to me, to be honest.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In `?par` we can find:

> In a layout with exactly two rows and columns the base value of "cex"
>   is reduced by a factor of 0.83: if there are three or more of either
>   rows or columns, the reduction factor is 0.66.

Therefore, when you change `mfrow` values from (2,  1) to (2, 3) the `cex` value changes from 0.83 to 0.66. `cex` affects font size and text line height.

So, you can manually specify `cex` value for your plots.

```
par(mfrow = c(mat.row, mat.col), mai = 0.2 * plot.mar, mgp = plot.mgp, cex = 1)
```

Hope, it is what you need.

Plot for `mat.row = 1` (cropped):
[image: mat.row = 1 (cropped)]
And plot for `mat.row = 3` (cropped):
[image: mat.row = 3 (cropped)]

Comment: Thanks a lot! These factors are exactly the ones I found empirically while experimenting with different rows and columns. It was driving me nuts, but that explains it. In my defense, I specifically avoided changing cex values, which is why I didn't suspect that the explanation would be hidden in ?par.